# Update application using Azure Automation DSC

Tags: azure, nodes, updates, dsc, azure-automation

How do I update application using Azure automation DSC?

When I change the configuration and upload and compile the configuration the status of the Vm node goes from `Complaint` to `Pending` status.

Then, I have to wait 30 min for the configuration to pickup the new config which then updates the application. I changed the package version too. Is there a way to force trigger the update?

Following is my code:

```
Configuration Deploy
{ 
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName cWebPackageDeploy
    Import-Dscresource -ModuleName PowerShellModule  

    node "localhost"
    { 
         cWebPackageDeploy depwebpackage  
         { 
            Name = "website.zip"
            StorageAccount = "testdeploy"
            StorageKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            Ensure = "Present"
            PackageVersion = "1.0"
            DeployPath = "C:\Temp\Testdeploy"
            DependsOn = "[PSModuleResource]Azure.Storage"
         }

          PSModuleResource Azure.Storage
         {
            Ensure = 'present'
            Module_Name = 'Azure.Storage'

         }
    }
} 

Deploy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of doing that using Azure Automation natively.
That being said you can always work around that by telling a vm to pull configuration with [Update-DscConfiguration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.0/dsc_updateconfig).

You can create a script that uploads the configuration, compiles it and forces a VM to pull from the pull server.

Comment: could you please me a bit do you mean that I create a script which creates a PS session and then trigger an Update-DscConfiguration from inside the vm? when I run  Update-DscConfiguration will it pull from Azure Automation DSC node configuration?